# How can I create a two-dimensional array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, file, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am currently trying to pass a 32 by 48 matrix file to a multi-dimensional array in Perl. I am able to access all of the values, but I am having issues accessing a specific value.

Here is a link to the data set:
http://paste-it.net/public/x1d5301/

Here is what I have for code right now.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open FILE, "testset.txt" or die $!;
my @lines = <FILE>;

my $size = scalar @lines;

my @matrix = (1 .. 32);
my $i = 0;
my $j = 0;
my @micro;

foreach ($matrix)
{
    foreach ($lines)
    {
        push @{$micro[$matrix]}, $lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: just ask the question and cut all else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem you understand that `$matrix` only indicates `@matrix` when it is immediately followed by an array indexer: `[ $slot ]`. Otherwise, `$matrix` is a completely different variable from `@matrix` (and both different from `%matrix` as well). See [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use English;
```

*Don't!* use English--*that way*!

This brings in `$MATCH`, `$PREMATCH`, and `$POSTMATCH` and incurs the dreaded `$&`, $`, `$'` penalty. You should wait until you're *using* an English variable and then just import that.

```
open FILE, "testset.txt" or die $!;
```

Two things: 1) use [*lexical* file handles](http://www.shlomifish.org/lecture/Perl/Newbies/lecture5/new-features/lexical-filehandles.html), and 2) use the three-argument [`open`](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/index.cgi?two_argument_open).

```
my @lines = <FILE>;
```

As long as I'm picking: Don't slurp big files. (Not the case here, but it's a good warning.)

```
my $size = scalar @lines;

my @matrix = (1 .. 32);
my $i = 0;
my $j = 0;
my @micro;
```

I see we're at the ["PROFIT!!"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StepThreeProfit) stage here...

```
foreach ($matrix) {
```

You don't have a variable `$matrix`; you have a variable `@matrix`.

```
    foreach ($lines) {
```

The same thing is true with `$lines`.

```
        push @{ $micro[$matrix]}, $lines;
    }
}
```

Rewrite:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw<$OS_ERROR>; # $!
open( my $input, '<', 'testset.txt' ) or die $OS_ERROR;

# I'm going to assume space-delimited, since you don't show
my @matrix;
# while ( defined( $_ = <$input> ))...
while ( <$input> ) {
    chomp; # strip off the record separator
    # Load each slot of @matrix with a reference to an array filled with
    # the line split by spaces.
    push @matrix, [ split ]; # split = split( ' ', $_ )
}
```

Comment: @Axeman FYI: `split` with no arguments is `split ' '` not `split /\s+/`

Comment: @Sinan: Not on redhat Perl 5.8.7 or Strawberry Perl 5.12.1:perl -MSmart::Comments
$_ = '1         2         3                        4     5';
my @a = split;
### @a

### @a: [
###       '1',
###       '2',
###       '3',
###       '4',
###       '5'
###     ]

Comment: @Sinan, well HTML compressed the spaces, but there are all sorts of spaces and tabs in there. :/

Comment: @Axeman: can you explain what you mean?  split with no arguments is definitely `split ' '`, not `split /\s+/`.  The two differ in how leading spaces are treated.

Comment: @Axeman See the CW answer I added to illustrate the difference.

Comment: @Sinan, @ysth, ah my reading of perlfunc is a little rusty. I had forgotten "As a special case, specifying a PATTERN of space (' ' ) will split on white space just as split with no arguments does". So I thought that the significance of `split( ' ' )` was it would only split on single-space characters--I only really use the shorthand of these functions in the toy code that I write on SO. You're right, @Sinan it *does* omit the initial zero-length string. My bad. And apparently that is simply to comply with *`awk`*.

Comment: @Sinan: I guess my *misguided* point was that `split()` behaves more like `split( /\s+/ )` than it does `split( $char )` with `$char = ' '` or `$char = ','`. The `' '` actually *hides* the full range of splitting behavior.

Comment: @Axeman that's why I thought I should give you a heads up. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to be doing quite a bit of math, you might consider [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org) (the Perl Data Language). You can easily set up your matrix and before operations on it:

```
use 5.010;

use PDL;
use PDL::Matrix;

my @rows;
while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my @row = split /\s+/;
    push @rows, \@row;
    }

my $a = PDL::Matrix->pdl( \@rows );
say "Start ", $a;

$a->index2d( 1, 2 ) .= 999;
say "(1,2) to 999 ", $a;

$a++;
say "Increment all ", $a;

__DATA__
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
2 3 4
```

The output shows the matrix evolution:

```
Start 
[
 [1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]
 [2 3 4]
]

(1,2) to 999 
[
 [  1   2   3]
 [  4   5 999]
 [  7   8   9]
 [  2   3   4]
]

Increment all 
[
 [   2    3    4]
 [   5    6 1000]
 [   8    9   10]
 [   3    4    5]
]
```

There's quite a bit of power to run arbitrary and complex operations on every member of the matrix just like I added 1 to every member. You completely skip the looping acrobatics.

Not only that, PDL does a lot of special stuff to make math really fast and to have a low memory footprint. Some of the stuff you want to do may already be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the values:

```
chomp( my @lines = <FILE> );
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify [a tangential point to Axeman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933505/need-help-creating-multi-dimensional-array-in-perl/3933974#3933974):

See [perldoc -f split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> A split on `/\s+/`  is like a `split(' ')`  except that any leading whitespace produces a null first field. A split with no arguments really does a `split(' ', $_)`  internally.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use YAML;

$_ = "\t1 2\n3\f4\r5\n";

print Dump { 'split'       => [ split       ] },
           { "split ' '"   => [ split ' '   ] },
           { 'split /\s+/' => [ split /\s+/ ] }
           ;
```

Output:

```
---
split:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
  - 5
---
split ' ':
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
  - 5
---
split /\s+/:
  - ''
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
  - 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the question is pretty old, but as the author has just edited the question, perhaps this is still of interest. Also the link to the data is dead, but since other answers use space as the separator, I will too.

This answer demonstrates [`Tie::Array::CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Tie::Array::CSV) which allows random access to a CSV (or other file parsable with [`Text::CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV)).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Array::CSV;

## put DATA into temporary file
## if not using DATA, put file name in $file
use File::Temp ();
my $file = File::Temp->new();
print $file <DATA>;
##


tie my @data, 'Tie::Array::CSV', $file, { 
  text_csv => {
    sep_char => " ",
  },
};

print $data[1][2];

__DATA__
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 1
2 3 4 5 6
```