# How can I create a multi-dimensional array in perl?

Tags: perl

I was creating a multi-dimensional array this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @a1 = (1, 2);
my @a2 = (@a1, 3);
```

But it turns out that I still got a one-dimensional array...

What's the right way in Perl?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a two-dimensional array in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933505/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-perl)

Comment: also of http://stackoverflow.com/q/317310/1084

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get a one-dimensional array because the array `@a1` is expanded inside the parentheses. So, assuming:

```
my @a1 = (1, 2);
my @a2 = (@a1, 3);
```

Then your second statement is equivalent to `my @a2 = (1,2,3);`.

When creating a multi-dimensional array, you have a few choices:

1. Direct assignment of each value
2. Dereferencing an existing array
3. Inserting a reference

The first option is basically `$array[0][0] = 1;` and is not very exciting.

The second is doing this: `my @a2 = (\@a1, 3);`. Note that this makes a reference to the namespace for the array `@a1`, so if you later change `@a1`, the values inside `@a2` will also change. It is not always a recommended option.

A variation of the second option is doing this: `my @a2 = ([1,2], 3);`. The brackets will create an anonymous array, which has no namespace, only a memory address, and will only exist inside `@a2`.

The third option, a bit more obscure, is doing this: `my $a1 = [1,2]; my @a2 = ($a1, 3);`. It will do exactly the same thing as 2, only the array reference is already in a scalar variable, called `$a1`.

Note the difference between `()` and `[]` when assigning to arrays. Brackets `[]` create an anonymous array, which returns an array reference as a scalar value (for example, that can be held by `$a1`, or `$a2[0]`).

Parentheses, on the other hand, do nothing at all really, except change the precedence of operators.

Consider this piece of code:

```
my @a2 = 1, 2, 3;
print "@a2";
```

This will print `1`. If you `use warnings`, you will also get a warning such as: `Useless use of a constant in void context`. Basically, this happens:

```
my @a2 = 1;
2, 3;
```

Because commas (`,`) have a lower precedence than equal sign `=`. (See "Operator Precedence and Associativity" in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity).)

Parentheses simply negate the default precedence of `=` and `,`, and group `1,2,3` together in a list, which is then passed to `@a2`.

So, in short, brackets, `[]`, have some magic in them: They create anonymous arrays. Parentheses, `()`, just change precedence, much like in math.

There is much to read in the documentation. Someone here once showed me a very good link for dereferencing, but I don't recall what it was. In [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) you will find a basic tutorial on references. And in [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) you will find documentation on data structures (thanks [Oesor for reminding me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425893/how-can-i-create-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-perl/6425961#6425961)).

Comment: when doing `1.Direct assignment of each value`,`$array[0][0] = 1;` is perl also creating and referencing anonymous array here since essentially perl array is one dimensional?

Comment: @Je Rog: Yes, `$array[0][0] = 1` is basically `$array[0] = [1]`. It can be read: "from the scalar reference of `array`, take the 0th element's 0th element and set it to 1", automagically creating an anonymous array to store it in. If you use `strict`, you will only need to declare `my @array`.

Answer (score 6):

I would propose to work through [`perlreftut`, `perldsc` and `perllol`](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html), preferably in the same day and preferably using [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) to print data structures.

The tutorials complement each other and I think they would take better effect together. Visualizing data structures helped me a lot to believe they actually work (seriously) and to see my mistakes.

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays contain scalars, so you need to add a reference.

```
my @a1 = (1,2);
my @a2 = (\@a1, ,3);
```

You'll want to read http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html.

Comment: @Oesor,how do do a deep copy on `@a1` so that if `@a1` changes,`@a2` doesn't?

Comment: @Je Rog: `my @a2 = ([@a1], 3);`

Comment: That works in some cases but not all; for ex. if @a2 is an array of objects. If it's a complex data structure at all you should use Storable or Clone to deep copy it to a reference.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev ,`{}` for hash and `()` for list,what does `[]` mean?

Comment: [ ] is for an array reference, { } is for a hash reference and ( ) is for a list, that you can assign to an array or a hash

Comment: @Je Rog no: `my $array_ref= [1,2];` vs `my @array= (1,2);` and you access the elements as `$array_ref->[0]` vs `$array[0]`

Comment: Why two commas?

Answer (score 2):

> The most important thing to understand
>   about all data structures in
>   Perl--including multidimensional
>   arrays--is that even though they might
>   appear otherwise, Perl **@ARRAY** s and
>   **%HASH** es are all internally
>   one-dimensional. They can hold only
>   scalar values (meaning a string,
>   number, or a reference). They cannot
>   directly contain other arrays or
>   hashes, but instead **contain references**
>   to other arrays or hashes.

Now, because the top level contains only references, if you try to print out your array in with a simple print() function, you'll get something that doesn't look very nice, like this:

```
    @AoA = ( [2, 3], [4, 5, 7], [0] );
    print $AoA[1][2];
    7
    print @AoA;
    ARRAY(0x83c38)ARRAY(0x8b194)ARRAY(0x8b1d0)
```

That's because Perl doesn't (ever) implicitly dereference your variables. If you want to get at the thing a reference is referring to, then you have to do this yourself using either prefix typing indicators, like `${$blah} , @{$blah} , @{$blah[$i]}` , or else postfix pointer arrows, like `$a->[3] , $h->{fred}` , or even `$ob->method()->[3]`

Source: [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

---

Now coming to your question. Here's your code:

```
my @a1 = (1,2);
my @a2 = (@a1,3);
```

Notice that the arrays contain scalar values. So you have to use reference and you can add a reference by using the `\` keyword before an array's name which is to be referenced.

Like this:

```
my @a2 = (\@a1, ,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inner arrays should be scalar references in the outer one:

```
my @a2 = (\@a1,3); # first element is a reference to a1
print ${$a2[0]}[1]; # print second element of inner array
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of a 2D array as ref:

```
my $AoA = undef;
for(my $i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
   for(my $j=0; $j<3; $j++) {
      $AoA->[$i]->[$j] = rand(); # Assign some value
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"as ref"*? *"as [a](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) reference"*? *"used as a reference"*? *"used through a reference"*? *As referenced somewhere on the Internet, e.g. in answers here or in the documentation? Or something else? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6429778/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: OK, [*sushant* has left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients), so we may never know.