# how to save person details in perl arrays

Tags: perl, tcl

I would like to save the student details in an array with the some keys in perl scripting how can i do it?

for example like in TCL

```
 array set student{}
 set student(ID1,name) = "abcd"
 set student(ID1,grade) = "A"
 set student(ID1,bloodGroup) = "A+"
 set student(ID2,name) = "abcd"
 set student(ID2,grade) = "B"
 set student(ID2,bloodGroup) = "O+"
```

is there a way how can I save the information like this in perl and extract the information based on the ID and name or grade or bloodgroup in perl?

Comment: You will probably want to do this with perl's hash variables, http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES

Comment: @rustyx arrays wouldn't really help here.

Answer (score 3):

Translating each of your TCL lines directly into Perl:

```
# This is an "associative array" and they are called "hashes" in Perl.
# array set student{}
my %student;

# set student(ID1,name) = "abcd"
$student{ID1}{name} = 'abcd';

# set student(ID1,grade) = "A"
$student{ID1}{grade} = 'A';

# set student(ID1,bloodGroup) = "A+"
$student{ID1}{bloodGroup} = 'A+';

# set student(ID2,name) = "abcd"
$student{ID2}{name} = 'abcd';

# set student(ID2,grade) = "B"
$student{ID2}{grade} = 'B';

# set student(ID2,bloodGroup) = "O+"  
$student{ID2}{bloodGroup} = 'O+';
```

To get the blood group of all the students, you could run code like this:

```
foreach (keys %student) {
  say "Student: $student{$_}{name}, Blood group: $student{$_}{bloodGroup}";
}
```

**Update:** If you had all of the data when you created the hash, then you could initialise all of the data structure in one statement.

```
my %student = (
  ID1 => {
    name => 'abcd',
    grade => 'A',
    bloodgroup => 'A+',
  },
  ID2 => {
    name => 'abcd',
    grade => 'B',
    bloodgroup => 'O+',
  },
);
```

Comment: Maybe you could show how to rewrite the hash assignment in a more Perlish way `%student = ( ID1 => { name => 'abcd', ...`

Comment: Good suggestion. Done.

Comment: Strictly, the 1-to-1 conversion would have code with `$student{"ID1,name"} = 'abcd';` but that's probably not translating the true intention.

Comment: You could even have something like `$student{'ID1','name'}` and rely on `$;` to make it work. But I really wouldn't recommend it :-/

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $student_data = {
    id1 => {
        name    => 'abcd',
        grade   => 'A',
        bloodgroup  => 'A+'
    },
    id2 => {
        name    => 'abcd',
        grade   => 'B',
        bloodgroup  => 'O+'
    }
};
print $student_data->{id1}->{name};
print $student_data->{id1}->{grade};
print $student_data->{id2}->{name};
print $student_data->{id2}->{grade};
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Yl5MlU)

Also read:

- [References in Perl [perlref]](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [Perl data structure [perldsc]](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use with hashes or multidimensional array for this better.

```
my @student = (
    { 
    'name' => 'abcd', 
    'grade' => 'A',
    'bloodgroup' => 'A+',
    },
);

print $student[0]{'grade'}, "\n";
```

[Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425893/how-to-create-multi-dimensional-array-in-perl)
[Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317310/how-can-i-create-multidimensional-arrays-in-perl)

Comment: I don't think that an array of hashes is a good way to model the original data. In the TCL code, the first level of the data structure was keyed on strings ('ID1', 'ID2') not integers, so I think that a hash of hashes is a better fit with the original code.

Comment: @Dave cross: That's I said use hashes or 2D arrays what ever. But sample I code 2d arrays